# Why is the program not returning YYText() or YYLeng()?

Tags: c++, lex, flex-lexer

I am attempting to create a lexical analyzer that will return the length of a token in a text file.

I have a text file with a single letter 'a' in it.

The following is my lex.l file

```
%option noyywrap 
%{
%}

/* regular definitions */
delim           [ \t\n]
ws              {delim}+
letter          [A-Za-z]
digit           [0-9]

%%

{ws}            {/* no action */}
letter          {return 1;}

%%
```

The following is the main program file that uses the YYText() and YYLeng() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lex.yy.cc"

using namespace std;

int OpenInputOutput(int argc, char *argv[], ifstream & lexerFIn, ofstream & lexerFOut)
{
// open input
if (argc > 1) {
    lexerFIn.open(argv[1]);
    if (lexerFIn.fail()) {
        cerr << "Input file cannot be opened\n";
        return 0;
        }
    }
else {
cerr << "Input file not specified\n";
return 0;
}

// open output
lexerFOut.open("Output.txt");
if (lexerFOut.fail()) {
    cerr << "Output file cannot be opened\n";
    return 0;
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
yyFlexLexer lexer; 
while (lexer.yylex() != 0) {
    cout << lexer.YYText() << endl;
    cout << lexer.YYLeng() << endl;
}
return 0; 
}
```

When I run the program with the aforementioned text file, with the command ./a "sample.txt", it writes 'a' on a file. Why doesn't it cout YYText() or YYLeng() or write the length of the character in the output file?

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you take a file name as a command line argument. It ignores the "sample.txt" you passed it.

Comment: Why on earth should it return 'a' and 1 from a file you've never opened anywhere in the program?

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to match `{letter}`?  `letter` (without the braces) matches exactly that six-letter literal.

Comment: @TimLandscheidt, but why doesn't it return the length?

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `YYText` or `YYLeng` after the parser has matched a token. You can't call them before parsing anything. You're retrieving properties of a match that never happened.

It's the same problem as if you randomly retrieved the value of `errno`.

Comment: How do I get the parser to match the token?

Comment: Call the parser's `yylex` method, typically in a `while` loop.

Comment: When I call lexer.yylex(), the program doesn't output anything. What is the proper syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. You mean it hangs in `yylex`?

Comment: What do you mean it hangs in yylex? I generated a C++ scanner, so I have to create lexer object and use its member functions. I can't call yylex() by itself. When I call lexer.yylex() the program just pauses without outputting anything. Why is this?

Comment: It's waiting for something to parse.

Comment: Why isn't it parsing the 'a' character in the text file?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't know how you have things set up. Why don't you update the question.

Comment: I just understood what you were asking in your earlier question. Yes, it hangs in yylex.

Answer (score 0):

The `yylex()` function will be reading from standard input unless you do something to make it work differently.  So, it is waiting on you to type a letter or white space.

Comment: Once I type a letter or whitespace, it returns what I typed. Why isn't it returning the length of the token, since I entered cout << lexer.YYLeng()?

Comment: I'm not sure.  When echo input, I'd surround it with other material, so I know what's really there: `cout << "Text: <<" << lexer.YYText << ">> (length: " << lexer.YYLeng() << ")" << endl;`.  That shows when empty strings are being printed, for example.  It also disambiguates between echoing by the terminal and echoing by the program.

Comment: Having experimented a bit, I don't understand where the default constructor for a `yyFlexLexer` is specified in the class, but I can tell you that it is not getting back into the body of your loop in `main()`.  Quite what it is up to, I'm not sure, but it is still inside the `lexer.yylex()` function and not in your main loop (which is why you're not seeing the length printed).

Comment: And further research shows that the header declares default arguments for a two-argument constructor, thus appearing like a default constructor...see the Flex manual [Generating C++ Scanners](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Cxx.html#Cxx)

Answer (score 0):

yylex () only returns for actions that `return VALUE;` or on EOF.  `cout << lexer.YYText() << endl;` & Co. is thus only executed for the input `letter`.

So you either need to move the output code to the scanner's actions or `return VALUE;` in every action.  NB: In the latter case I don't know if the values of yytext/yylen are guaranteed to exist and be meaningful after returning to yylex ()'s caller.